# Javascript debugging in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Although I found several questions regarding this topic, I'm not finding any luck solving my own issue. My lack of javascript knowledge is most likely the cause of that. Anyway, it would be great if someone could help me with this.

I've implemented several javascripts in the html. They all seemed to work but somehow in the end it didn't when I fired up IE again to test it. I ran a debugging test on IE and this was warning came up: 'nodeType' is null or not an object. I'm not totally sure which part of the script to post so below is the entire script part of the html:

HEAD

```
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />

    <link href="tablecloth/tablecloth.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tablecloth/tablecloth.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  


    var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();  
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.twitter.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
        $jq(document).ready(function() {
            $jq("#twitter").getTwitter({
                userName: "ronnsono",
                numTweets: 2,
                loaderText: "Loading tweets...",
                slideIn: false,
                showHeading:false,
                headingText: "Latest Tweets",
                showProfileLink: false
            });
        });
    //--><!]]>
    </script>
```

BODY

```
    <!-- The JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.transform-0.9.3.min_.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var $menu           = $('#mb_menu'),
            $menuItems          = $menu.children('a'),
            $mbWrapper          = $('#mb_content_wrapper'),
            $mbClose            = $mbWrapper.children('.mb_close'),
            $mbContentItems     = $mbWrapper.children('.mb_content'),
            $mbContentInnerItems= $mbContentItems.children('.mb_content_inner');
            $mbPattern          = $('#mb_pattern'),
            $works              = $('#mb_imagelist > li'),
            $mb_bgimage         = $('#mb_background > img'),

            Menu                = (function(){

                var init        = function() {
                    preloadImages();
                    initPlugins();
                    initPattern();
                    initEventsHandler();
                },
                //preloads the images for the work area (data-bgimg attr)
                preloadImages   = function() {
                    $works.each(function(i) {
                        $('<img/>').attr('src' , $(this).children('img').data('bgimg'));
                    });
                },
                //initialise the jScollPane (scroll plugin)
                initPlugins     = function() {
                    $mbContentInnerItems.jScrollPane({
                        verticalDragMinHeight: 40,
                        verticalDragMaxHeight: 40
                    });
                },
                /*
                    draws 16 boxes on a specific area of the page.
                    we randomly calculate the top, left, and rotation angle for each one of them
                 */
                initPattern     = function() {
                    for(var i = 0; i < 16 ; ++i) {
                        //random opacity, top, left and angle
                        var o       = 0.1,
                        t       = Math.floor(Math.random()*196) + 5, // between 5 and 200
                        l       = Math.floor(Math.random()*696) + 5, // between 5 and 700
                        a       = Math.floor(Math.random()*101) - 50; // between -50 and 50

                        $el     = $('<div>').css({
                            opacity         : o,
                            top             : t + 'px',
                            left            : l + 'px'
                        });

                        if (!$.browser.msie)
                            $el.transform({'rotate' : a + 'deg'});

                        $el.appendTo($mbPattern);
                    }
                    $mbPattern.children().draggable(); //just for fun
                },
                /*
                    when the User closes a content item, we move the boxes back to the original place,
                    with new random values for top, left and angle though
                 */
                disperse        = function() {
                    $mbPattern.children().each(function(i) {
                        //random opacity, top, left and angle
                        var o           = 0.1,
                        t           = Math.floor(Math.random()*196) + 5, // between 5 and 200
                        l           = Math.floor(Math.random()*696) + 5, // between 5 and 700
                        a           = Math.floor(Math.random()*101) - 50; // between -50 and 50
                        $el         = $(this),
                        param       = {
                            width   : '50px',
                            height  : '50px',
                            opacity : o,
                            top     : t + 'px',
                            left    : l + 'px'
                        };

                        if (!$.browser.msie)
                            param.rotate    = a + 'deg';

                        $el.animate(param, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
                    });
                },
                initEventsHandler   = function() {
                    /*
                        click a link in the menu
                     */
                    $menuItems.bind('click', function(e) {
                        var $this   = $(this),
                        pos     = $this.index(),
                        speed   = $this.data('speed'),
                        easing  = $this.data('easing');
                        //if an item is not yet shown
                        if(!$menu.data('open')){
                            //if current animating return
                            if($menu.data('moving')) return false;
                            $menu.data('moving', true);
                            $.when(openItem(pos, speed, easing)).done(function(){
                                $menu.data({
                                    open    : true,
                                    moving  : false
                                });
                                showContentItem(pos);
                                $mbPattern.children().fadeOut(500);
                            });
                        }
                        else
                            showContentItem(pos);
                        return false;
                    });

                    /*
                        click close makes the boxes animate to the top of the page
                     */
                    $mbClose.bind('click', function(e) {
                        $menu.data('open', false);
                        /*
                            if we would want to show the default image when we close:
                            changeBGImage('images/default.jpg');
                         */
                        $mbPattern.children().fadeIn(500, function() {
                            $mbContentItems.hide();
                            $mbWrapper.hide();
                        });

                        disperse();
                        return false;
                    });

                    /*
                        click an image from "Works" content item,
                        displays the image on the background
                     */
                    $works.bind('click', function(e) {
                        var source  = $(this).children('img').data('bgimg');
                        changeBGImage(source);
                        return false;
                    });

                },
                /*
                    changes the background image
                 */
                changeBGImage       = function(img) {
                    //if its the current one return
                    if($mb_bgimage.attr('src') === img || $mb_bgimage.siblings('img').length > 0)
                        return false;

                    var $itemImage = $('<img src="'+img+'" alt="Background" class="mb_bgimage" style="display:none;"/>');
                    $itemImage.insertBefore($mb_bgimage);

                    $mb_bgimage.fadeOut(1000, function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        $mb_bgimage = $itemImage;
                    });
                    $itemImage.fadeIn(1000);
                },
                /*
                    This shows a content item when there is already one shown:
                 */
                showContentItem     = function(pos) {
                    $mbContentItems.hide();
                    $mbWrapper.show();
                    $mbContentItems.eq(pos).show().children('.mb_content_inner').jScrollPane();
                },
                /*
                    moves the boxes from the top to the center of the page,
                    and shows the respective content item
                 */
                openItem            = function(pos, speed, easing) {
                    return $.Deferred(
                    function(dfd) {
                        $mbPattern.children().each(function(i) {
                            var $el         = $(this),
                            param       = {
                                width   : '100px',
                                height  : '100px',
                                top     : 154 + 100 * Math.floor(i/4),
                                left    : 200 + 100 * (i%4),
                                opacity : 1
                            };

                            if (!$.browser.msie)
                                param.rotate    = '0deg';

                            $el.animate(param, speed, easing, dfd.resolve);
                        });
                    }
                ).promise();
                };

                return {
                    init : init
                };

            })();

            /*
                call the init method of Menu
             */
            Menu.init();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm not going to fire up an IE instance to try to replicate this, but in my experience that error is usually thrown by a jQuery plugin being passed an empty input and not handling it gracefully.

Comment: please post a better explanation of the problem

Comment: I tried to explain that beginner level of javascript isnt sufficient to understand any of it. The core problem is that one of the scripts isnt working and I'm suspecting a conflict somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in IE8 with 'nodeType' is null or not an object. The solution which I found to update your jQuery with latest version.